# Selenium Add EventListener to RemoteWebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, events

I'd like to add an EventListener to an instance of `RemoteWebDriver`. Is this in any way possible or is there an alternative way to achieve the same thing in selenium (except mayby to implement an Observer pattern and code everything from ground up).

I have tried to use the `EventFiringDecorator` and the `WebDriverListener`, but the `decorate(WebDriver driver)` method returns an instance of `ByteBuddy` that is then casted to `(WebDriver)` and returned, so the returning instance of `WebDriver` can not be casted to `RemoteWebDriver`.

I would like to add the listener optionally, like in the following code snippet, when creating an instance of RemoteWebDriver.

```
class Foo {

 private RemoteWebDriver driver = null;

 public RemoteWebDriver initializeDriver() {

     //setup of remoteWebDriver
     //...

     if(eventListenerIsActivated) {
         MyEventListener myEventListener = new EventListener(driver);
         EventFiringDecorator eventFireDec = new EventFirirngDec(myEventListener);

         //not possible, throws ClassCastException!
         driver = (RemoteWebDriver) eventFireDec.decorate(driver); 
     }
     return driver;
 }
}

class MyEventListener implements WebDriverListener { //... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
EventFiringDecorator eventFireDec = new EventFirirngDec(myEventListener).decorate(driver); 

WrapsDriver wrapperAccess = (WrapsDriver) eventFireDec;

driver = (RemoteWebDriver) wrapperAccess.getWrappedDriver();
```